# Write dict to file with each key/value pair on a separate line

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm currently in the process of writing an account registration program in Python. The program uses a file called `players` that has a dictionary written to it with keys corresponding to the player's username, and the other information (email, password, age and gender) as an array associated to the respective key.

The `accounts` dictionary is defined as so depending on whether or not the `players` file exists and it is empty.

```
def is_file_empty(filename):
    return os.stat(filename).st_size == 0

def create_file(filename, mode = 'w'):
    f = open(filename, mode)
    f.close()

if os.path.exists('players'):
    with open('players', 'r') as f:
        if is_file_empty('players'):
            accounts = {}
        else:
            accounts = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
else:
    create_file('players')
    accounts = {}
```

It is then written to the file using a function inside of a `Player` class.

```
def write(self):
        accounts[self.name] = [self.email, self.password, self.age, self.gender]
        with open('players', 'w') as f:
            f.write(accounts)
```

It works fine, however, due to the way it's being written, it always occupies a single line. I want to try writing each key/value pair on its own line within a dictionary, but I have absolutely no idea how to accomplish this.

**How can I do so?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I may suggest a different approach: use existing, simple serialisation schemes like JSON or YAML instead of manually rolling your own:

```
import json

try:
    with open('players.json', 'r') as file:
        accounts = json.load(file)
except (OSError, ValueError):  # file does not exist or is empty/invalid
    accounts = {}

# do something with accounts

with open('players.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(accounts, file, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate over the items in your dictionary and write each line separately, like this:

```
def write(self):
    accounts[self.name] = [self.email, self.password, self.age, self.gender]
    with open('players', 'w') as f:
        for key, value in accounts.items():
            f.write('{0}, {1}\n'.format(key, value)
```

Comment: Might want to edit that a bit. I'm trying to write them still within a dictionary so it can be read through `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: In that case, I'd go with @deceze's answer.